Cold Shower Question?
A friend of mine wants to grow muscles as their ultimate goal. To start, my friend wakes up at around 7am and takes a cold bath for 5 minutes followed by some yoga and push-ups. Then they do high-intensity cardio at 11:50 am for 10 minutes. Afterward, at 4 pm, they do a one-day abs workout, and the other day arms and legs workout for around one hour and a half to two hours so they finish their workout at around 6 pm. My friend's question is after waiting 2 hours after their workout, would a 10-15-minute cold shower be beneficial or would that reduce the muscle growth? They did research online, where one expert/gym person says you should wait an hour and then you can take a cold shower, while others say you should wait 4-6 hours after a workout to take a cold shower. So this is where the confusion starts to settle into which source to trust.

It appears that, based on several studies, CWI (cold water immersion) lessens muscle hypertrophy!
According to the European Journal of Sports Science,

Resistance training in combination with cold water immersion may still induce gains in muscle mass but to a lesser degree compared to resistance training alone.
(Piñero, A., Burke, R., & al,  et. (2024, February 5)).

Source: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/ejsc.12074
I would also focus on adequate protein intake (1g protein per pound of bodyweight), sufficient sleep and proper recovery.

CWI is completely different from a cold shower. The temps are colder, the surface area exposed larger, and exposure time longer.

CWI lowers inflammation and DOMS, thus enables to go hard faster again after a hard session, yet some of these processes improve hypertrophy. So when you need training time (like in team sports or for neuromuscular adaptation), yes, when all you need is hypertrophy (which is not the same as strength), don't do it. Cold shower is a light version of CWI with lower effects.

Many CEOs have been taking ice baths for years, so the impact on energy recovery is quite good at the very least, as well as on anabolic processes

The last part of your answer is evidently false. It has inflammation suppressant and dopaminergic effects, which are the main positive things scientifically informed people aim at when using them.

CEOs (which ones?) taking ice baths has no correlation with muscle growth.
